# Why doesn't Google Eclipse Plugin GWT compiler recognise Ivy dependency classpathentry?

Tags: java, gwt, maven, ivy, ivyde

At present, I have an ANT build which takes care of integrating Ivy dependency for both Javac and GWT compile very well.

What puzzles me is, why doesn't the GPE GWT compiler recognise the eclipse classpathentry in the .classpath file?

> <classpathentry kind="con"
>         path="org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.cpcontainer.IVYDE_CONTAINER/?project=z.gwt.zebra&ivyXmlPath=ivy.xml&confs=*&ivySettingsPath=%24%7Bworkspace_loc%3Az.gwt.zebra%2Fivysettings.xml%7D&loadSettingsOnDemand=false&propertyFiles=%24%7Bworkspace_loc%3Az.gwt.zebra%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fzebra.properties%7D"/>

Why does the GPE GWT compiler have no trouble recognising a maven dependency classpathentry, but refuses to acknowledge Ivy's classpathentry?

Could someone with GPE internals intimacy educate me on this curiosity and possibly suggest a recourse (even if the recourse meant having to change GPE code - not that I will attempt to make such changes but it would at least allow me more satisfactory sleep at night). Though, I would prefer a simple remedy.

*Note: Please don't suggest that I write an ANT build because ... please read my first paragraph.*

Comment: Are you sutre that the path is `ivySettingsPath=%24%7Bworkspace_loc%3Az.gwt.zebra%2Fivysettings.xml%7D&loadSettingsOnDemand=false&propertyFiles=%24%7Bworkspace_loc%3Az.gwt.zebra%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources%2Fzebra.properties%7D`, should it be decoded?

Comment: You can try to use `file:///path/to/project/z.gwt.zebra/ivysettings.xml` instead of `${workspace_loc:z.gwt.zebra/ivysettings.xml}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting a bug in IvyDE:

See:

- https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6225
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVYDE-335