# Eclipse combining multiple classpathentry hierarchically into the same output

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I have the following records in my projects's `.classpath` file:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/webapp"
 output="build/webapp"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"
 output="build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"
 output="build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes"/>
```

My intention is

1. copy `src/main/webapp` into `build/webapp`
2. then compile `src/main/java` into `build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`
3. then copy `src/main/resources` into `build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`

However the result is actually,

- copy `src/main/webapp` into `build/webapp`
- prevent `build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` from ever existing, but maintain the exact copy between `src/main/webapp` and `build/webapp`

Which means `build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` can never be created and steps 2 & 3 never successful.

I even tried modifying step 1 to

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/webapp" output="build/webapp"
 excluding="WEB-INF/classes/**"/>
```

which did not help at all.

The order of the classpathentry records are inconsequential.

**Q1.**
Please help advise how I should write my classpathentry records to hierarchically combine them into the same output directory, so that a classpathentry of a higher folder hierarchy would not nullify a classpathentry of a lower folder hierarchy.

**Q2.**
BTW, I cannot find any document specification for the xml tags and tag-attributes for eclipse `.classpath` file. I have tried googling "eclipse classpathentry" to no avail. Could someone also point me to a document?

- Are "exported", "excluding", "kind", "path", "output" the only attributes for the classpathentry tag?
- What other tags are allowed in the .classpath file, for example?
- A functional explanation for each of those tags and tag-attributes.

Comment: I misunderstood steps 2 and 3. Do you really want to copy .java files from src/main/java to build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes, I believe you do not want that. You want to compile it (typically into build folder) and copy compiled .class files to WEB-INF/classes, right?

Comment: You are right. IT should be compiling src/main/java into build/webapp/WEB-INF/classes. I'll correct it.

Comment: Is it possible to migrate the project to maven or gradle? This might help you to get a clean and standardized project structure and with the m2eclipse plugin, the eclipse integration makes things a lot easier.

Comment: We are already doing it with Ant + Maven/Ivy. However, I am hoping to do this as a favour for colleague who want to be able to test/compile/debug/hotswap straight from the IDE buttons.

Comment: when my pom.xml is changed I perform mvn eclipse:eclipse and everything is set correctly (of course with project refresh in eclipse)

Comment: Actually, it's for a project with Ivy dependency. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039936/why-doesnt-google-eclipse-plugin-gwt-compiler-recognise-ivy-dependency-classpat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, .classpath is not intended to be edited manually. This file is configuration file of JDT. Files with names starting with "." are intended to hidden from User. If you edited this file manually, in some cases, there will be broken synchronization with actual configuration object (JDT is okay, since configurations are automatically synchronized in JDT)

Open Properties Dialog of your project, select "Java Build Path". Then you can see GUI editor for that file. That GUI will answer what you asked. It allows to manage src to output mapping, re-ordering and etc. But it will not help you nest output the way you asked.

An output folder cannot be hierarchically nested under another other output folder. Because there may cause conflicts. I am sure syntax will not help you. It will not let you do what you intend.

This file is just derived stored data. If your needs are strong, you should have to consider custom build script, or hire some eclipse engineer to make builder extension for your needs.

Comment: My apologies, I have been using the way you describe since Eclipse 3.3. However, I frequently had to edit .classpath manually, to do what the GUI would not config for me. Now, I need answer for the syntax of .classpath xml elements which I had never bothered to find out so far - even though we "are not supposed to" edit the file ourselves.

Comment: An output folder can not nesting another other output folder. Because there may be conflict. I can sure syntax will not help you. JDT Compiler not worked by this file, This file is just derived store data. If your needs is strong, You should have to consider custom build script, or hire some eclipse engineer to make builder extension for your needs.